# make [1] leaving directory error

Tags: kernel

When I run `make` command for patching CRCN on ns2 under Ubuntu 12.04, I am faced with this error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/apadana/ns-allinone-2.31/ns-2.31/indep-utils/cmu-scen-gen/setdest'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/apadana/ns-allinone-2.31/ns-2.31/indep-utils/cmu-scen-gen/setdest'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/apadana/ns-allinone-2.31/ns-2.31/indep-utils/webtrace-conv/dec'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/apadana/ns-allinone-2.31/ns-2.31/indep-utils/webtrace-conv/dec'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/apadana/ns-allinone-2.31/ns-2.31/indep-utils/webtrace-conv/epa'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/apadana/ns-allinone-2.31/ns-2.31/indep-utils/webtrace-conv/epa'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/apadana/ns-allinone-2.31/ns-2.31/indep-utils/webtrace-conv/nlanr'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/apadana/ns-allinone-2.31/ns-2.31/indep-utils/webtrace-conv/nlanr'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/apadana/ns-allinone-2.31/ns-2.31/indep-utils/webtrace-conv/ucb'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/apadana/ns-allinone-2.31/ns-2.31/indep-utils/webtrace-conv/ucb'
```

What's wrong?

I would be grateful if somebody could help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on the output you have provided, nothing is wrong. Those messages are informational, not error messages.

Comment: In all likelihood, `make` succeeded once. Running it again has no effect.

Comment: You could attempt to remove the output of the first run, or even attempt ```make uninstall``` but that depends on if this makefile has a procedure for that

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar error `make [1]: Leaving directory` on Ubuntu 18.04.

You need to install in `/opt` - it is a directory where to install unbundled packages, each in its own subdirectory.

I install luajit in `/opt` (instead of `/home`):

`# cd /opt`

`# ./configure ; make ; make install`

The system automatically **redirects** the installation to the `/usr/local` folder. This error disappears for me:

```
ln -sf luajit-2.0.5 /usr/local/bin/luajit
==== Successfully installed LuaJIT 2.0.5 to /usr/local ====
```